# An argument of 'simple string' type was used but a 'series bool' is expected

Tags: pine-script

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")




Co5_10_b =  input.bool(defval = true , title = "Cross 5 , 10")
Co15_25_b = input.bool(defval = true , title = "Cross 15 , 25")




Co5_10 = ta.crossover(ta.rsi(close , 5) , ta.rsi(close , 10))
Co15_25 = ta.crossover(ta.rsi(close , 15) , ta.rsi(close ,25))


textt = "Hi"
titlee = "Hi"
colorr = color.white
locationn = location.abovebar

longCondition = if Co5_10_b == true and Co15_25_b == false
    Co5_10
    textt := "Cross Over 5 , 10"
    titlee := "CO5_10 " 
    colorr := color.green
    locationn := location.belowbar
else
    if Co5_10_b == false and Co15_25_b == true 
        Co15_25
        textt := "Cross Over 15 , 25"
        titlee := "Co15_25 "
        colorr := color.green
        locationn := location.belowbar
    else
        if Co5_10_b == true and Co15_25_b == true
            Co5_10 and Co15_25
            textt := "Double Co"
            titlee := "Double CO"
            colorr := color.green
            locationn := location.belowbar

plotshape(longCondition , text = textt ,title = titlee ,color = colorr  , location =locationn )
```

whuy i get errorwith thiscode and how i can fix it ?

my error is

ine 45: Cannot call 'plotshape' with argument 'series'='longCondition'. An argument of 'simple string' type was used but a 'series bool' is expected

Cannot call 'plotshape' with argument 'text'='textt'. An argument of 'simple string' type was used but a 'const string' is expected

Cannot call 'plotshape' with argument 'title'='titlee'. An argument of 'simple string' type was used but a 'const string' is expected

Cannot call 'plotshape' with argument 'location'='locationn'. An argument of 'simple string' type was used but a 'input string' is expected